# Migrate from Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: migration

My Mac has failed, and I need a new machine.  I have a full Time Machine backup.  I'd like to switch to Ubuntu (or some other Linux distro) rather than buying another Mac.  If I do so, will I be able to recover my files?  Where can I find instructions?

Comment: It depends on what is the backup format. We have no idea what is Mac "full Time Machine backup" here and how to get files from there. Maybe you would need another Mac for that. i wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Pilot6 fuse filesystem with some custom alterations (they used the 2nd column in `ls -l` to store a directory number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual method:

Mount the drive with the backup using the `-t hfsplus` option.

If you mount it in media you will have something like this:

```
/media/{mountpoint}/Backups.backupdb/Drive/{date}/
```

{date}: the newest data obviously has the newest backup. `ls -l` will show a list of directories with a number behind the permissions. The data is actually stored in a hidden dir and with that number like this:

```
cd /media/{mountpoint}/.HFS+ Private Directory Data/dir_{the number you found}/
```

and you can use `cp` to copy your data to a Ubuntu partition.

Some scripts others made to automate it:

- [Script fuse-time-machine](https://github.com/isnotajoke/fuse-time-machine) (2012).
- [Script copy-from-time-machine.sh](https://gist.github.com/vjt/5183305) (2014).
- [Script tmfuse](https://github.com/rpedde/tmfuse) (2014).
- [Script restoretmbackup.py](https://github.com/iiegn/pub/blob/master/src/restoretmbackup.py) (2009).